# Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type '[{ id: string; gp: boolean; }]

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's what the interface look like

```
 export interface Patient {
    doctors: [{
      id: null,
      gp: null,
     }]
  }
```

Here's my tuple

```
  linkedDoctorShort: Array<any> = []; // will contain only the ID and GP
```

I tried some solutions that I had found on StackOverflow, but I still got the same error, especially when I want to save all the information:

```
  onSave() {
    const patientInfo: Patient = {
    doctors: this.linkedDoctorShort,
  };
```

Error message :

> Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type '[{ id: string; gp: boolean; }]'.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`linkedDoctorShort: Array<any> = [];` is not a tuple. It is an array initialized with an empty array.

If you want this to be an array (`doctors` can have any number of elements) use an array type in the interface

```
 export interface Patient {
    doctors: Array<{
      id: null,
      gp: null,
     }>
  }
```

If you want only a single element (ie a tuple of length one). Then use that in the type of  `linkedDoctorShort` and initialize it accordingly:

```
export interface Patient {
    doctors: [{
        id: null,
        gp: null, // are you sure these can only be null ? I think you mean soemthing like string | null
    }]
}

let linkedDoctorShort: [any] = [{ id: null, gp: null }]; //  Or better yes let linkedDoctorShort: [Patient['doctors'][0]] to keep type safety 

const patientInfo: Patient = {
    doctors: this.linkedDoctorShort,
};
```

Comment: my bad the interface is actually id: string and gp: boolean (edit: thank you i dont get the error anymore i had to change the interface thank you so much)

Comment: @M.Ela either way, solution is the same, that just looked weird to me :)

Answer (score 3):

Change your interface to:

```js
export interface Patient {
  doctors: Array<{id: string;gp: boolean;}>;
}
```

But I'm not a huge fan of inline typing. I prefer a cleaner syntax, like:

```js
export interface Doctor {
  id: string;
  gp: boolean;
}

export interface Patient {
  doctors: Doctor[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

despite the error you encounter, suggestion is clear type definition.

```
export interface Doctor {
    id: string | number;
    gp: boolean;    
}
export interface Patient {
    doctors: Doctor[];
}
```

Just as @jpavel said. then you can use the advantage of Typescript.

```
const linkedDoctorShort:Doctor[] = [];
onSave() {
    const patientInfo: Patient = {
    doctors: this.linkedDoctorShort,
};
```

you won't miss it