# Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type '[{ post_id: string; title: string; }]'

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I've looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474226/property-0-is-missing-in-type-any-but-required-in-type-id-string-gp) but I still don't get what the problem is..Why can't I pass this array to the update call?

```
    // create object with new post props
    const newPost = await this.postRepository.create(data);
    await this.postRepository.save(newPost);

    // push postid into posts array
    const posts = [];
    posts.push({
      post_id: newPost.post_id,
      title: newPost.title,
    });

    const updatedUser = {
      posts,
    };

    // update user to contain the posts array
    await this.userService.edit(data.user_id, updatedUser); // error on updatedUser
```

```
export interface UserDTO {
  user_id: string;
  name: string;
  posts: [
    {
      post_id: string;
      title: string;
    },
  ];
}
```

Comment: Does explicitly typing the posts variable help? `const posts: UserDTO['posts'] = [];`. Also I don't think that's valid syntax in your interface. Try `posts: Array<{ post_id... }>;`

Comment: The syntax `[T]` is valid but it's talking about a [tuple](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), in this case, an array of exactly one element of type `T`.  If you want an array of zero or more elements of type `T`, you should use `T[]` instead, or the equivalent `Array<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
posts: [
    {
      post_id: string;
      title: string;
    },
  ];
```

This makes `posts` a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), not (just) an array. It's saying that `posts` will have exactly one element, and that element will be of type `{ post_id: string, title: string }`.

When you create this array:

```
const posts = [];
```

... it's just a plain simple array of `any`. It might have 1 element, or more, or less. It's therefore not a match for the tuple, because there's no way to enforce that it has the right contents.

Most likely, it was a mistake to make it a tuple, and you should change the type definition to:

```
posts: {
  post_id: string;
  title: string;
}[]
```

On the other hand if it is supposed to be a tuple, then you'll need to make the variable be of that type as well, as in:

```
const posts: [{ post_id: string, title: string }] = [{
  post_id: newPost.post_id,
  title: newPost.title,
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an array!** It's a *tuple*, containing exactly one element.

```js
posts: [
    {
      post_id: string;
      title: string;
    },
]
```

What you want is an array:

```js
posts: {
  post_id: string;
  title: string;
}[]
```